# How do I "export" things from a submodule?

Tags: module, rust

I'd like to write a `mod.rs` file like:

```
pub use foo::*;

mod foo;
pub mod bar;
```

But I get the error `unresolved import foo`. What's the correct way to do this?

Comment: It's possible to inline `foo.rs` into `mod.rs`, and then have all other modules (e.g. `bar`) reference `foo`'s contents by using `super::[thing]`, but that seems unwieldy, especially when exporting multiple modules' contents.

Comment: [Seems to work](http://is.gd/4Wsyxn) as you've written it. I've defined the module bodies inline as empty because your example has none. Perhaps you need to refine your failing example to produce an [MCVE](/help/mcve)?

Comment: That works, but embedding it in another submodule [doesn't](http://is.gd/uZoJeU).

Comment: Please [edit] your question to include the actual failing example, the [one in your comment](http://is.gd/uZoJeU).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Here's an [MCVE](/help/mcve) of your problem:

```
pub mod sub {
    use foo::function;

    pub mod foo {
        pub fn function() {}
    }
}

fn main() {}
```

As [Adrian mentions](https://stackoverflow.com/a/31767485/155423), the solution is to use the keyword `self` in the `use` statement:

```
pub mod sub {
    use self::foo::function;

    pub mod foo {
        pub fn function() {}
    }
}

fn main() {}
```

So, what's going on? [*The Rust Programming Language*](http://doc.rust-lang.org/stable/book/crates-and-modules.html#re-exporting-with-pub-use) describes the problem:

> What about the `self`? Well, by default, use declarations are absolute paths, starting from your crate root. `self` makes that path relative to your current place in the hierarchy instead.

That is, `use foo` means to use `foo` from the root of the crate. `use self::foo` means to use `foo` relative to the current module.